# Handling Android dynamic text string in res/values

Tags: android

Let's say I have this string:

*Your player has a **good** keeper skill and a **decent** people skill*

Now the part not in bold of the string is always the same, what is known at runtime is the part in bold.

So how could I do something like:

*Your player has a **{var1}** keeper skill and a **{var2}** people skill*

and then fill those vars at runtime with right values?

I do not want to concatenate strings like:

```
"You player has a"  + var1  + "keeper skill and a"  + var2 + "people skill"
```

Comment: `Resources.getString(resId, ...)` or `Context.getString(resId, ...)` with string like `"You player has a %1$s keeper skill and a %2$s people skill"` is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to see Android string resource guide. There is a way to provide static string which can be later formatted with variables.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

You will define string like

```
<resources>
  <string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have &lt;b>%2$d new messages&lt;/b>.</string>
</resources>
```

And later in code you can replace

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages), username, mailCount);
CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
```

Comment: tnx, your getting the answer accepted for completeness in links and code.

Comment: more info about formatting string tokens at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: 'fromHtml(String!): Spanned!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Answer (score 11):

in Strings.xml

```
You player has a %1$d  keeper skill and a %2$d people skill
```

in java

```
getString(R.string.article_stats, var1, var2);
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, see the following from [android devguide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

If you need to format your strings using `String.format(String, Object...)`, then you can do so by putting your format arguments in the string resource. For example, with the following resource:

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

In this example, the format string has two arguments: %1$s is a string and %2$d is a decimal number. You can format the string with arguements from your application like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(
    res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages),
    username, mailCount);
```

Answer (score 3):

in strings xml you have define html syntax in CDATA tag like

```
<![CDATA[<b> %1$s bought </b>, last purchased from %2$s <b> %3$s </b>]]>
```

and in your java class

```
String detail =  String.format(getString(R.string.detail),15,"New Delhi","23 mins ago");
        detailView.setText(Html.fromHtml(detail ));
```