# Android: Change menu item from Log in to Log out

Tags: android, menu

My menu has a item to Log in, but when you are logged in I want it to say Log out.

How?

If I'm going to change the item after its created, its probably through this method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate( R.menu.menu_main, menu );
    return true;
}
```

Afaik the onCreateOptionsMenu() happens after the onCreate so putting any getItemId() for the menu there will give me a NullPointerException right away.

I want the app to find out if its supposed to use the string R.string.Logout if its logged in.

I dont even know what to search for for this issue. All I found was how to make a string implement names, like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7646689/3064486

Comment: please post some code if you expect a proper answer. Hard to tell what's being asked here

Comment: fair enough, updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` instead to update menu items

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);


        MenuItem someMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.some_menu_item);
        someMenuItem.setTitle("Log out");
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

To refresh Menu items call `invalidateOptionsMenu();`from Activity

From Android API guides: "If you want to modify the options menu based on events that occur during the activity lifecycle, you can do so in the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method. This method passes you the Menu object as it currently exists so you can modify it, such as add, remove, or disable items. (Fragments also provide an onPrepareOptionsMenu() callback.)"

Answer (score 0):

After you inflate a menu, you can customize its items. To get each one, you must call [`findItem()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#findItem%28int%29) with the item's id. In particular, you can use [`setTitle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to change the displayed string.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    if (mIsLoggedIn)
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_login).setTitle("Log out");

    return true;
}
```

where `action_login` is the id you set for this particular menu item in the menu's xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void updateUI() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
                MenuItem nav_signin = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_signin);
                nav_signin.setTitle(MyApp.signedIn ? "Sign out" : "Sign in");
        }
    });
}
```